# Achieve single inflate of a layout by avoiding multiple inflate and stacking one over another

Tags: android

Im calling an Alert Activity when some condition is not met. But if this alert layout is already popped up then I want to avoid inflating it again. I'm using the below code :

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsAlertActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            this.startActivity(intent);
```

Problem here is, new alert layout is getting opened whenever the condition is not met. Its getting stacked even though I'm setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.
What is wrong in my code?

Comment: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` try with this in place of `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` it will not add activity to the history stack.

Comment: try removing `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and use only clear top , Let me know your device version'

Comment: I think `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` is the right flag for this.

Comment: I had tried that but Alert page did not trigger even once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP won't do much good if you're using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK... a new task has nothing to clear.

Assuming you have to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK because you have no current task then consider using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK instead of FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.